# ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module while installing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I have installed TensorFlow 2.0 with CUDA 10.1, cuDNN SDK = 7.6 and all the different libraries such as pandas, sci-kit learn, Keras, NumPy, Gensim etc. This error is probably due to new TensorFlow version. When I try to confirm it by running this confirmation code. I am getting an error. Kindly help.

```
import sys

import tensorflow.keras
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import tensorflow as tf

print(f"Tensor Flow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Keras Version: {tensorflow.keras.__version__}")
print()
print(f"Python {sys.version}")
print(f"Pandas {pd.__version__}")
print(f"Scikit-Learn {sk.__version__}")
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

**Error I am getting:**

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\distributions\distribution.py:265: ReparameterizationType.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.distributions.distribution) is deprecated and will be removed after 2019-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
The TensorFlow Distributions library has moved to TensorFlow Probability (https://github.com/tensorflow/probability). You should update all references to use `tfp.distributions` instead of `tf.distributions`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\distributions\bernoulli.py:169: RegisterKL.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.distributions.kullback_leibler) is deprecated and will be removed after 2019-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
The TensorFlow Distributions library has moved to TensorFlow Probability (https://github.com/tensorflow/probability). You should update all references to use `tfp.distributions` instead of `tf.distributions`.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-0b3eb45acbe5>", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow.keras
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ModuleNotFoundError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1151, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import compat
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import experimental
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\compat\v1\experimental\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_v2_toggles import output_all_intermediates
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_v2_toggles.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_util_v2
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_util_v2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer_utils
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\applications\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import engine
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 56, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.hdf5_format import load_attributes_from_hdf5_group
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 42, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\metrics.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer
ImportError: cannot import name 'Layer' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer' (C:\Users\Abdul\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

​
```

Comment: Can you show how you installed the libraries, and which ones?

Comment: using pip install library name. I have installed  sklearn, pandas, pandas-datareader, matplotlib, spacy, gensim, spacy

Comment: Are you not using Conda?

Comment: No, I have used pip for installing the different libraries

Comment: I meant aren’t you using Conda for virtual environments?

Comment: I am not too sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial to install everything.

Comment: https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/manual_setup.ipynb

Comment: _I am not too sure what you are trying to ask._ Conda is both a tool for managing virtual environments, and for managing dependencies/libraries. You said you're not using it to install libraries, so I was asking if you are using it for the virtual environment in this case.

Comment: Hi @Abdul Wahab, Have you tried reinstalling on a new conda virtual environment?

Answer (score 12):

If you get this error on Google colab, then factory reset the runtime. Click on Runtime, then factory reset runtime

Comment: Ditto for any jupyter kernel. Gold - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If happen in `Google Colab`:
In top menu click `Runtime` > `Restart Runtime`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by downloading and installing 
"Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019". It worked for me.

Pre-requisite: Python + Jupyter notebook + tensorflow installation already done

You get this error when you "import tensorflow"

Follow the below steps:

Step 1: Download "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 - community edition"

Step 2: Select "Python Workload" while installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

Step 3: Restart your computer once

Step 4: That's it now open Jupyter notebook and "import tensorflow" and the error will not occur

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on a Windows 10 VM. Since you're using Anaconda, try:

`pip uninstall tensorflow`

Then try `conda install tensorflow`

Then try to import your Keras packages via: `from tensorflow.keras.xxx import xxx`

As mentioned in the comments above, it might be worth a try setting up a virtual environment in conda, and installing the required packages there.

Answer (score 0):

In Anaconda you cannot see the pip uninstall prompts you with "Do you want to continue (Y/N)? Therefore you should add --yes: pip uninstall tensorflow --yes